# What is the Maximum Number of Electrons per Angstrom Cubed?

Tags: electrons, x-ray-crystallography

Upon some reading, it has come to my knowledge that electron density is measured in number per Angstrom cubed. I assume, since electrons take up 'space', that there is some sort of maximal number of electrons that can fit into a cubic Angstrom. If I am correct in this conclusion, what is this upper limit?

This question pertains to a project I am working on, in which I want to create a program that generates an electron density diagram for a molecule. My goal is to represent each cubic Angstrom (or any other cubic unit) on a scale from $0$ to $1$, $0$ being no electrons in that cubic Angstrom, and $1$ being the aforementioned maximum number. I am nervous that I might be mistaken in thinking this a good representation, and so would be happy if anyone could correct me (if I am mistaken, what could be a better representation? If there is no upper limit, could I change the scale to go from $0$ to $\infty$?).

Comment: When you compress elementary particles sufficiently, all sorts of strange things can happen.  Consider neutron stars.    Also of possible interest:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter

Comment: perhaps this as well  https://www.quora.com/Can-free-electrons-be-compressed-and-if-so-can-they-be-compressed-into-a-container-Why-or-why-not

Comment: Valence electrons only, or total electrons (metallic uranium has about 7 time as many electrons per unit volume than metallic aluminum does, for example).